# Generating subsets of a finite magma

Tags: magma

I am trying to write a program which, given a multiplication table of a finite magma $(G, *)$, should produce at least one (or all possible) generating subset $S$ of minimal cardinality.

More precisely $S \subset G, \ |G| = n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $<S>$ be operational closure of $S$ in $G$. I am interested in outputting at least one $S$, such that $<S> = G$ and for every $S'$ with that property $|S| \le |S'|$.

So far I have tried to understand what is $<a>, a \in G$, but due to lack of even simple associativity this is non-trivial. I defined right-associative power operation $a^k := (k = 1) \ ?\  a \ :\  a * a^{k-1}$, for $k \ge 1$. I already know how to list the elements of a set $R_a := \{a^k \ |\ k \ge 1\}$, and of similarly defined set $L_a$, if $a^k$ is defined as left-associative. These are, in general case, proper subsets of $<a>$, and need not even be closed under multiplication (I have constructed counterexamples).

All in all, proper description of $<a>$ still evades me, but even then, I would have to figure out how to describe $<a_1,...,a_k>$ knowing the former. Is there a more intelligent way to write this program than absolute brute force search across subsets of $G$ and the definition of $<S>$ as intersection of all submagmas of $G$ that contain $S$?

Comment: Be aware that [groupoid is used to refer to a different notion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupoid), and I believe this usage is much more common than how you've used it, which I think is to be a [magma -- set with a binary operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra)). So it's worth defining the term when you use it, to make it easier for the reader to know what you mean. I've adjusted the tags to reflect what I think you mean.

Comment: This is what I had in mind. Magma. In my language it is called a groupoid. This was a real terminological surprise. Appreciate the heads-up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I wrote the algorithm which literally follows the mathematical definition:

Let $G$ be the magma.

```
    GeneratingSets := EmptySet; 
    Iterate A over the power set of G {
        S := G;
        Iterate B over the power set of G {
            if((A is contained in B) and (B is a submagma)) {
                S := S intersect B;
            }
        }
        if(card(S) equals card(G)) {
            GeneratingSets := GeneratingSets union Set(A);
        }
    }
```

There is, however, a more efficient way to do this. Since $G$ is finite, any subset $H$ of $G$ is finite as well, so the closure of $H$ can be computed with the following iterative procedure:

```
   Closure := H;

   do {
       m := card(Closure);
       R := EmptySet;
       Iterate over (a, b) where a, b are in Closure {
           R := R union Set(a * b);
       }
       Closure := Closure union R;
   } while(card(Closure) > m);
```

It is not difficult to see that it is guaranteed to stop, because $G$ is finite. So now we can iterate over all subsets of $G$ only once, also sparing us the tedious intersection computations.

This is the most efficient method I can think of for now, but I doubt much more can be done without any additional requirements imposed upon $(G, *)$.